# Как правильно говорить: "за водой" или "по воду"?

Tags: фразеология

-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта нормативны.
По воду (по грибы, по ягоды) - более соответствует народно-поэтической речи, за водой - нейтральной.
Известная присказка "За водой пойдёшь - не воротишься" не отражает литературной нормы.